# decode string encoded by Escape()(a method in VBScript) in php

Tags: decode

I have a string encoded by Escape in VBScript:

> The Escape function returns a string
>   (in Unicode format) that contains the
>   contents of charString. All spaces,
>   punctuation, accented characters, and
>   other non-ASCII characters are
>   replaced with %xx encoding, where xx
>   is equivalent to the hexadecimal
>   number representing the character.
>   Unicode characters that have a value
>   greater than 255 are stored using the
>   %uxxxx format http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3607h29%28VS.85%29.aspx.

How do i decode the string in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`urldecode($string)`](http://php.net/urldecode)

Although this may not work properly if there are non-ASCII characters encoded in the string. There's a user-submitted note on the documentation page that provides code for a function called `decode_unicode_url($str)` that should do the trick if you actually have Unicode characters in the string.

Comment: Thanks David. urldecode() decodes Escape().
A good online tool to check the results: http://coderstoolbox.net/string/